# Delete from multiple tables based on date

Tags: mysql, inner-join, sql-delete

I am trying to delete records with the same id from 3 tables. The tables are something like this:

```
Table1
+----------+----------------+-----------+---------+----------+
| commonid | creation_date  | column 1  | column 2| column 3 |
+----------+----------------+-----------+---------+----------+

Table2
+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| commonid | column 1| column 2 | column 3| column 4 |
+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+

Table3
+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| commonid | column 1| column 2 | column 3| column 4 |
+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
```

So to select all the data I am using

```
SELECT * FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.commonid = table2.commonid 
INNER JOIN table3
ON table1.commonid = table3.commonid
WHERE creation_date = '2018-08-01 04:13:50'
```

Which would return 6 rows. To delete I will try:

```
DELETE table1 FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.commonid = table2.commonid 
INNER JOIN table3
ON table1.commonid = table3.commonid
WHERE creation_date = '2018-08-01 04:13:50'
```

Which returns 1 row affected, I would have expected 6. When I run the first query again I get 0 results. The total rows for table 3 are not affected.

How do I delete rows with the same `commonid` from each table?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify all three tables as targets for the deletion:

```
DELETE t1, t2, t3
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.commonid = t2.commonid 
INNER JOIN table3 t3
    ON t1.commonid = t3.commonid
WHERE
    creation_date = '2018-08-01 04:13:50';
```

Currently, you are only telling MySQL to delete from `table1`.